# USB Drive sometimes changes the Drive name

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, fstab, usb-drive, fdisk

I have two USB Drives, I created partitions, and formatted it to ext4.
Running `fdisk -l` shows that I have /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1

```
Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  
/dev/sdb1
```

Then I mounted both on boot by running `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

I use Samba to access it from the different computer and most of the time it is working fine, but sometime I can't access the files via samba and running `fdisk -l` shows the the device for my drives changed to for example /dev/sdc1. Sometimes it changes only per one drive and sometimes for both.

I have no idea why it happened. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps poor contact in the connectors, causing the drives to lose power and/or data connectivity? The next time you see a drive with a changed device name, check the output of `sudo dmesg -H`. You might see errors accessing the disk by old name, and later the disk being re-detected with the new name. Seeing the actual error messages might help figuring out more about the reason.

Comment: From `man fstab`: "LABEL=<label>  or  UUID=<uuid>  may  be  given instead of a device name.  This is the recommended method, as device names are often a coincidence of hardware detection order, and can change when other disks are  added or  removed".  you would be strongly advised to label the USB srive partitions and change `/etc/fstab` accordingly.

Comment: Many suggest using autofs for external devices. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs  Similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795819/usb-drive-partitions-change-randomly-on-boot And noauto or nofail if boot issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047109/how-can-i-delay-mount-of-secondary-internal-hard-drive-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment1710066_1047109 more info:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab

Comment: @telcoM It's raspberry pi 4 model B and I have 2 1TB USB drives plugged to it with standard power adaptor. Do you think it may not be powerful enough for two external drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea why it happened

the convention `/dev/sda` {for example} is a *mount by-name*.  If all you had was 1 disk, i.e. your operating system disk, that would always be `/dev/sda`.  So no problem.  Add more disks, you get `sdb` and `sdc` and so on.  Mount by-name does not care or respect order or sequence all the time.  So once your operating system disk is mounted by-name as `sda` then subsequent [usb] disk attachments show up in sequence as `sdb` and `sdc`.  *That's the only way mount by-name respects any kind of order*.  Do mount by-name in `/etc/fstab` so that mounting happens at boot, and order sequence is *not respected*.  Maybe it goes by pci bus number order i don't know.  But you will observe that your operating system disk no longer mounts first as `sda`.  So you take your chances on using mount by-name in `/etc/fstab` {best i can do on describing it}.

For a running system, to temporary plug in a [usb] disk then mount by-name is acceptable.  But for reliability and to not experience exactly what you did, do not use mount by-name in `/etc/fstab` to have devices mount that way at boot time, it's just bad practice now.

Mount either `by-uuid` or `by-label`.  You have made the EXT4 partitions on your usb sticks, so put a label on them as well such as *stick1* and *stick2* and then use that mount syntax convention in `/etc/fstab`.  The first column in `/etc/fstab` instead of having `/dev/sda3  /` for your operating system disk for example could be something like these two

```
UUID=800e924a-a869-4152-9533-9d9cfecbd19e  /
    or
LABEL=rootpartition /
```

look under `/dev/disks/`  to see the different mount conventions.

you could of course mount your usb disks by UUID {universally unique id} once you get that uuid of them, but a partlabel would be easier typing and remembering and be just as reliable... until you use someone else's usb stick that coincidentally has the same label syntax.